# Intersection of prime ideals in Boole ring with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a Boole ring with identity (i.e. $a^2=a$ for all $a$). Then the intersection of all prime ideals in $R$ is known to be equal to $R$'s nilradical, which is $\{0\}$.

Is there a way to show that the intersection of all prime ideals (which is actually also the intersection of all maximal ideals, because this is a Boole ring) is $\{0\}$ without this result?